# using xpath to select elements in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, xpath

Is there a plugin to allow me to do this? It says [here (*XPath Compatibility Plugin*)](http://docs.jquery.com/Release%3ajQuery_1.2#XPath_Compatibility_Plugin) that the functionality was removed back in Jquery version 1.2 and the plugin it links is gone!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most browsers support [`document.evaluate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.evaluate) for selecting elements with XPath expressions - no jQuery required.  The only major browser lacking support is Internet Explorer.  Dimitri Glazkov has [created a library](http://glazkov.com/2004/04/06/xpath-unleashed/) that will implement the missing functionality for IE, however.

```
var result = document.evaluate("//a[@href='#']", document, null, 0, null),
    item;

while (item = result.iterateNext()) {
    // item will be an <a> element with href="#" here
}
```

You could easily create a plugin to wrap this functionality too:

```
(function($) {
    $.xpath = function(exp, ctxt) {
        var item, coll = [],
            result = document.evaluate(exp, ctxt || document, null, 5, null);

        while (item = result.iterateNext())
            coll.push(item);

        return $(coll);
    }
})(jQuery);

// And call it like so:
$.xpath("//a[@href='#']").click(function () { return false; });
```

Comment: a better solution is shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068272/getting-a-jquery-selector-for-an-element where you can just use the string as a native css selector

Comment: @Michael: that question and solution are unrelated to this one.  This one asks how you can select elements using XPath syntax, that one asks how you can create a CSS selector for an already selected element.  You can't really say either is better than the other because they both approach different problems.