# Track ALL clicked elements using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, onclick, element, tracking

I want to track ALL elements that are clicked on a HTML-page. I need a good way to reference exactly which element was clicked (so I will be able to replay the clicks on a identical separate HTML-page later on).

**Is there a good way to reference which element that was clicked?**

I could add unique id's and classnames to every single element on the page. But I figure there must be another way?

The HTML-page which I will be replaying the clicks on will be identical.

Something like this (but more exact information which element it was, maybe that's possible to collect)...

**Code to track which element was clicked**

```
var arrayWithElements = new Array();

document.onclick = clickListener;

function clickListener(e) {
    var clickedElement;
    if(e == null) {
        clickedElement = event.srcElement;
    } else {
        clickedElement = e.target;
    }
    arrayWithElements.push(clickedElement)
    alert(arrayWithElements);
}
```

**Code that will be used on a identical HTML-page**

```
document.someHowGetTheElement().onclick();
```

Comment: Adding IDs to each element is probably the easiest way. You can add them with JavaScript as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "more exact information" , currently clickedElement will give you a reference to the node, I don't know what can be more exactly than this.

Comment: @James: `this` will refer to `document`, not the clicked element. @Dr.Molle: He mentions to "replay" the events on another page. You cannot really persist or transfer references to DOM nodes.

Comment: Thanks DR.Molle. Let's say there are 100 nested divs and images. How would you know wich image that was clicked? Please help if you know how! :)

Comment: Thanks Felix Kling. You wouldn't perhaps know a good method to add ID to every element? eg. start on king1,king2,king3,king4 and so on ;D

Comment: @user1087110: Well, no two nodes are identical. If you have a reference to a node (`event.target`) you have the element. But it seems you want to use that information on another page in which case you have to serialize the reference somehow. As I said, IDs might be the easiest way. You could also generate the XPath for the node, but that could be more complicated to do across browsers.

Comment: Regarding IDs: Just have a counter and a prefix and iterate over all elements while increasing the counter. Whether this is a good approach depends on the number of elements though.

Comment: Thanks Felix :) Aproximatly how many elements will make this ID method into a "bad approach"?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

---

```
var arrayWithElements = new Array();

function clickListener(e) 
{   
    var clickedElement=(window.event)
                        ? window.event.srcElement
                        : e.target,
        tags=document.getElementsByTagName(clickedElement.tagName);

    for(var i=0;i<tags.length;++i)
    {
      if(tags[i]==clickedElement)
      {
        arrayWithElements.push({tag:clickedElement.tagName,index:i}); 
        console.log(arrayWithElements);
      }    
    }
}

document.onclick = clickListener;
```

---

It will store on every click an object that contains the tagName of the element and the index.
So you may access this element in another "instance" of this document by using

```
document.getElementsByTagName(item.tag)[item.index]
```

(where *item* is an item of arrayWithElements)

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/z2wds/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/z2wds/)

Comment: Impressed! I think that's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much :)

Comment: +1 Good idea. It might be worth caching the results of `getElementsByTagName`.

Comment: Yes it does, I've applied the proposal

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068272/getting-a-jquery-selector-for-an-element). In other words,  a good way to know which element was clicked without adding IDs all over the place is to use jquery's `.cssSelectorAsString()` method. For example:

```
function clickListener(e) {
    var clickedElement;
    if(e == null) {
        clickedElement = event.srcElement;
    } else {
        clickedElement = e.target;
    }
    arrayWithElements.push($(clickedElement).cssSelectorAsString()); // <====
    alert(arrayWithElements);
}
```

See also: [Get unique selector of element in Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706837/get-unique-selector-of-element-in-jquery)

Comment: I'm not using jquery (forgot to mention). But I will look into the xPath mentod! Thanks!