# Record count after clicking a hyperlink in Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint, hyperlink, click, counter, sharepoint-list

Is there any way to record click rate of the hyperlink in Sharepoint List item after clicked?

We have a column in a Sharepoint List storing a report hyperlink, we want to record how many click of the link by user. Is there any way to do without using Powerapps or flow? Thanks for any suggestion.

Joanne

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no quick and easy solution for this. Personally, I would leverage [SharePoint Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview) (SPFx) to create an extension which would then allow you to run javascript on the site. From there you could then add events to links on the page for [tracking purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509231/track-all-clicked-elements-using-javascript). For storing the click events you have several options such as writing to a SP List, back-end service, application insights, etc.

I don't think Power Automate (aka Flow) will help here as the events are tied to modifications (update/create/delete).

Note: Perhaps you could link to some sort of redirection service instead of the report directly, which would record the click, then forward to the report. This would avoid the need for SPFx.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I think leverage SPFx is little difficult for me as I am a newbie in Sharepoint. But I will study it because it's good to have javascript work at the site. I finally use PowerApps to add count into Sharepoint List on Powerapps onSelect event.