# Generate an elements selector using Prototype

Tags: prototypejs

For a project i am currently working on i need to be able to pass an elements absolute path/ selector to a ajax request.

I found this stackoverflow answer which shows [how this can be achieved using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068272/getting-a-jquery-selector-for-an-element), which i would love to use, however the project requires the use of prototype.

I was thinking about using:

```
.previousSiblings().size()
```

for indexing the current element, but not sure what to replace:

```
 name += ':eq(' + index + ')';
```

(particularly :eq) for the path selector string.

I need to be able to select the same element again using prototypes $$('path') selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This jsfiddle should help you

http://jsfiddle.net/s7aWH/

I took the answer from the other stackoverflow answer and ported to PrototypeJS

the jQuery `.index()` is similar to the Prototype `.indexOf()`

and you can still use the ':eq()' CSS selector but you need to increment by one

Comment: Cool, i like the use of `.indexOf()` and `:eq()` however it will currently only work for one loop.... on line 17 `node = parent;` node has no length `console.log(node.length); so the loop will stop at that point. This only happens if you run the script when the div has more layers of parents and therefore you don't get a full path.