# Selectors in javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript

How to get value of particular selector with same class?

```
function rev() {
  var username = document.getElementByClass(value).value; /// or textContent;
  return alert (username);
}

                <a href="#" class="but" onclick="rev()">Hey</a>
                <a href="#" class="but" onclick="rev()">Hey2</a>

                <button class="but" onclick="rev()">hey</button>
                <button class="but" onclick="rev()">NOww</button>
```

But the reult always HEY

Any ideas?

Comment: "How to get value of particular selector" — Selectors don't have values. They are ways to identify elements (or pseudo-elements) in a document.

Comment: "with same class" — The same class as what?

Comment: ids should always be unique, there shouldn't be two ids which are the same. If your goal is to echo the value of the clicked element, use `alert($(this))`

Comment: `var username = document.getElementByClass(value).value` — This will always throw a ReferenceError and abort the script because the `value` variable is undeclared. If it didn't, it would throw "Not a function" because `getElementByClass` is `undefined`

Comment: You need to provide a clear problem statement and a real [mcve] (preferable in the form of a live demo, the stackoverflow question editor has a button for adding live demos, use it).

Comment: @andrew — That is why I said it was `undefined`

Comment: I found a question regarding building selectors based on the location in the DOM: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068272/getting-a-jquery-selector-for-an-element Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to get the `innerText` of each element with the class of `but`, then `alert` that `value/innerText` based on the element that was clicked...

You could grab all `buts` then supply each `but` with an `onclick` method like so:

```
var buts = document.getElementsByClassName('but');
var keys = Object.keys(buts);

keys.forEach(function(but, idx) {
  buts[idx].onclick = function() {
    var username = buts[idx].innerText;
    alert(username);
  };
});
```

This will `alert` the `Hey` for the `first but`, `Hey2` for the `second but`, etc.... You can see the example working here:

http://jsbin.com/yunulayihi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: lmao ridiculous, why did someone decide to downvote clearly valid solutions to what this person is asking...?

Comment: Yeah... I'm the above -- I'm upvoting yours back to 0. We suggested similar things, and unless I'm missing something about the question (or someone has a specific beef they're just not willing to state), there's no reason for our answers to be downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Your question as asked has multiple issues, and I'm assuming it's intended to be pseudocode, because it wouldn't even get as far as returning 'Hey' as written.

Firstly, I believe you're intending to use [getElementByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), not 'getElementByClass'

Secondly, I think you want `textContent`, not `value` from the clicked element.

But as far as your problem, I think the issue is that you're calling:

```
document.getElementByClassName('but').value
```

Which effectively means that when rev() is called, it searches the document for ALL instances of `.but` and looks for an object property called 'value'...

Instead, you want the textContent of just the element whose `onclick` event has been triggered. To do that, you need to capture the event in your event handler function, `rev()`

Here's a way you can attach `rev()` function as the 'click' event handler to all items in the document with the className `.but` -- note that I removed the function rev() from the HTML onclick attribute, and instead it gets added do each element when `.map()` loops through and calls `button.addEventListener()`:

```js
var buts = document.getElementsByClassName('but');
var buttons = Array.prototype.slice.call(buts);

buttons.map(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', rev);      
});

function rev(e) {
  
  // This is the element targeted by the current event.
  var element = e.target;
  
  // Assuming you want 'Hey', 'Hey2', etc.
  var value = element.textContent;
  
  alert(value);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="#" class="but">Hey</a>
  <a href="#" class="but">Hey2</a>

  <button class="but">hey</button>
  <button class="but">NOww</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The short answer is really: to get some specific value from an element which is listening for an event, you have to capture the event object -- the 'target' property of the event object is the element listening on the event.

Comment: Was this not what you were asking how to do? I'm just curious why it's downvoted.

Answer (score -3):

you can use each function in jquery to get text

```
 $('.but').each(function(){
   $(this).text()   // you can access any attribute for this class 
 });
```

Comment: Hi what's the problem with this code  to give me -3 reputation ?

Comment: I didn't downvote you myself, but the problems I see are that it uses jQuery while the question is plain JS, which means that firstly the asker would have to add jQuery as a dependency in order to use your solution. Secondly, while your code would identify the text content for each item on the page, it won't do what the asker wants... I think they want the '.but' items to listen for a click event and return only their own textContent. Clicking the link with 'Hey2' should call `alert('Hey2')`, etc.