# how can I implement copy css selector as like chrome using JQuery to take screenshot of particular div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am letting user to take screenshot on div user clicking on  from url, but how can I get css selector **Ex.(#clients > div > div > div:nth-child(1))** to capture the screenshot.
[image: chrome copy selector]

using jquery how can I achieve that, please help me with that.

Comment: It's not clear to me. Do you want the user to get a selector when he clicks on a div ? Do you want to copy the HTML code of an element when the user provides a selector ? Or is it something else ?

Comment: @Tom , No, I have user's website inside iframe, so when user clicks on any div or section i want css selector of that div so will take screenshot of that div using [urlbox.io]  service but that service  need target selector to capture it

Comment: how about? `$(document).on("click",".col-lg-2",function(){
  var gotClickedElement = $(this).html();
});` I am not sure wether this works with iframe

Comment: @stillKonfuzed from this I will get only html content but I need css selector  when user click on any of the div

Comment: oh you mean the classname? you can do `$(this).css();`  for css or `$(this).prop('class');` for classnames or if conditional then  `$(this).hasClass('some-classname');`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a jQuery selector for an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068272/getting-a-jquery-selector-for-an-element)

Comment: @stillKonfuzed see this https://imgur.com/a/tCFDyJJ ,I want targetSelector like this section:nth-child(2) , not only classname  or id or element

Comment: @Tom yeah some what similar but I am not able to use that fucntion as it is giving unexpected token 'class' , how can use it like normal fucntion like  ```$(document).on("click","#iframe",function(e){   getPath(e.target); 
 //or $(this) });```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer fot this using library which generates CSS selectors from DOM nodes [jhartikainen/dompath](https://github.com/jhartikainen/dompath) and it easy to implement.
Just add `dompath.js` script into your file.
**USAGE :**

```
e.target.contentDocument.body.addEventListener('click', e => {
    targetSelector= '';

    //call function, pass any element:
    var csspath = dompath(e.target);

    //get CSS selector:
    targetSelector = csspath.toCSS();
    console.log(targetSelector);
    //#about > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(1)
});
```